# Faster LDA implementation

Tags: python, numpy, lda

I am implementing the LDA, and avoiding using out-of-box libraries. I tried with python / numpy. With 1 million records and a vocabulary size of ~2000, It takes around 7 mins for **ONLY 1 run** of sequential GibbsSampling. Using distribute LDA version with 8 processes speeds it up to ~5mins 
Distributed LDA:: Every process will do a sequential GibbsSampling over a subset of the total matrix, and once done the respective output matrices are added up.

Is there any way to make it any faster? Replacing the implementation in another language all together?

Adding more records ~linearly increases the time required. In my use case I need to run LDA over ~25 million documents, which might mean around ~144 mins for 1 run!!! And then atleast 100 runs of LDA to ensure that the modle almost converges!!!!

Code: https://pastebin.com/AmEwTuUu

Reference: https://github.com/shuyo/iir/tree/master/lda

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far with `numpy`?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AmEwTuUu

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at a Microsoft's [LightLDA](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightLDA). They've developed a more efficient sampler that is able to be distributed. The [underlying paper](http://www.www2015.it/documents/proceedings/proceedings/p1351.pdf) claims that their method is nearly a magnitude faster.

In case you want to stick to python you can find a port here:
https://github.com/nzw0301/lightLDA.